# Where can I find wayland?

Tags: xorg, display, wayland

Mark Shuttleworth [writes](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/551) that wayland will be replacing X in the future in Ubuntu. Where can this software be found?

Comment: Well.. I really would like to find the software. No really a question of differences or quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is :

- [Home page](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server%29)
- [Source Code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/wayland)

Comment: post at omgubunu: http://goo.gl/PvvGR

Answer (score 2):

See http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Wayland